# How to show shop on Google Product Knowledge Panel

Tags: knowledge-graph

I have been trying to get my ecommerce shop to show up on the Google Product Knowledge Panel which is a sub category of the Google Knowledge Panel and mainly fed by datafeed information from the Google Merchant Program.

I have supplied every possible information in my datafeed and on my website via structured data however my shop still doesn't show up.

Does anyone know what is required to show up as shop on the Product Knowledge Panel?

So here is my product schema:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Product",
      "mpn": "HL-495",
      "sku": "igHL-495",
"gtin": "9318674442240",      "image": ["https://www.site.com.au/images/Products/2023/HL-495.jpg"
,"https://www.site.com.au/images/Products/2024/HL-495-1.jpg","https://www.site.com.au/images/Products/2024/HL-495-2.jpg"],
      "name": "Cabac Tool Crimp HL-495",
      "description": "Cabac Tool Crimp  HL-495, RJ45 FEED THROUGH PLUG CRIMP TOOL... Crimps and cuts Open-Pass RJ45 modular plug -- Exposed wire ends are automatically trimmed off with flat and neat surface after crimped -- Handle lock provides better safety in closed position and easy storage -- Parallel crimping action ensuring precise termination -- Cuts and strips CAT 6A, CAT6, CAT5e round cables -- Compact fits hand well and function consistently meets performance requirements -- Dual-color grip handle enhances comfort, Handle: PP(Blue) + TPR(Black) -- Length: 5.62 (142.8mm +/- 3mm), Weight: 246g -- Warranty: 1 Year",
"category": "Tool Crimp",
      "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "Cabac"
      },
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "https://www.site.com.au/products/link--Cabac--Tool-Crimp--5--Buy--HL-495.htm",
        "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/NewCondition",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "price": "65.90",
        "priceCurrency": "AUD",
        "priceValidUntil": "2024-03-14",

"hasMerchantReturnPolicy": {
          "@type": "MerchantReturnPolicy",
          "applicableCountry": "AU",
          "returnPolicyCategory": "https://schema.org/MerchantReturnFiniteReturnWindow",
          "merchantReturnDays": 14,
          "returnMethod": "https://schema.org/ReturnByMail",
          "returnFees": "https://schema.org/FreeReturn"
        },


        "shippingDetails":
{
          "@type": "OfferShippingDetails",
          "shippingRate": {
            "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
            "value": "14",
            "currency": "AUD"
          },
          "shippingDestination": {
            "@type": "DefinedRegion",
            "addressCountry": "AU"
          },
          "deliveryTime": {
            "@type": "ShippingDeliveryTime",
            "handlingTime": {
              "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
              "minValue": 0,
              "maxValue": 1,
              "unitCode": "DAY"
            },
            "transitTime": {
              "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
              "minValue": 1,
              "maxValue": 3,
              "unitCode": "DAY"
            }
          }
}
        
      },



      "review": {
        "@type": "Review",

          "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
            "ratingValue": 5,
            "bestRating": 5
          },
          "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "John"
          }
        },
        "aggregateRating": {
          "@type": "AggregateRating",
          "ratingValue": 5,
          "reviewCount": 1
        }
      }
</script>
```

Then here is my breadcrumb schema:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": [
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 1,
        "name": "Home",
        "item": "https://www.site.com.au"
      },{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "name": "All Brands",
        "item": "https://www.site.com.au/products/browsebybrand.htm"
      },{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 3,
        "name": "Cabac",
        "item": "https://www.site.com.au/products/brand--Cabac.htm"
      },{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 4,
        "name": "Cabac Tool Crimp",
        "item": "https://www.site.com.au/products/Cabac--Tool-Crimp.htm"    
      }
,{"@type": "ListItem","position": 5,"name": "Cabac Tool Crimp HL-495","item": "https://www.site.com.au/products/link--Cabac--Tool-Crimp--5--Buy--HL-495.htm"}      

    ]
    }
</script>
```

To your "Google My Business" info, I have been verified for over 10 years and never had a problem with that part. Also been on Yelp etc for over 10 years.

Also, always had my phone number, address, return policy, terms and conditions, about us on my site and clicking on the 3 dots Google states this site was first indexed more than 10 years ago.

So I think all of the above is all favourable but as you mentioned when it comes to authority I believe it is very low...to explain....Google never liked my site structure hence it never indexed my final product pages or category pages....I fixed that only about 1 month ago so Google only started indexing all my pages(about 5000) around that time....this is the only reason I can imagine my shop isn't listed in those panels.

And I focus nationally in Australia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to provide a better answer to you if you convey what you have tried.

> I have supplied every possible information in my datafeed and on my
> website via structured data however my shop still doesn't show up.

The information is picked up from the schema, specifically the offer for a product ... Going to the "compare prices" in the Google Panel will pull up all of the ecommerce shops with the correct schema.

Note: Walmart store, ebay, and others automatically create the schema for products listed on those sites. Here is an example just pulled from "compare prices" of an ebay product.

```
[{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "name": "eBay",
            "item": "https://www.ebay.com"
        },
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "name": "Electronics",
            "item": "https://www.ebay.com/b/Electronics/bn_7000259124"
        },
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 3,
            "name": "Cell Phones & Accessories",
            "item": "https://www.ebay.com/b/Cell-Phones-Smart-Watches-Accessories/15032/bn_1865441"
        },
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 4,
            "name": "Cell Phones & Smartphones",
            "item": "https://www.ebay.com/b/Cell-Phones-Smartphones/9355/bn_320094"
        }
    ]
},{
    "@type": "Product",
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "name": "Samsung Galaxy S24 S921B 256GB 8GB RAM GSM Unlocked International Version (New)",
    "image": "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/fA8AAOSwP~hlsptK/s-l1600.jpg",
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/325987684313?chn=ps&mkcid=28&var=515040137890&srsltid=AfmBOoo7HHf4M79zYIh6ht_aEQ6NjdZLbLUcCkISaW_Dn2VFVAF10zmLuVM",
        "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/NewCondition",
        "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
        "priceCurrency": "USD",
        "price": "819.99",
        "shippingDetails": {
            "@type": "OfferShippingDetails",
            "shippingRate": {
                "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
                "value": "0.0",
                "currency": "USD"
            }
        }
    },
    "model": "Galaxy S24",
    "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "Samsung"
    }
}]
```

The "@type": "Product", is what is being pulled, the content must exist on the page, but the schema is unambiguous so it is what is used. "@type": "BreadcrumbList", may be useful for the purpose of topical authority or the "EE" part of EEAT to qualify

To move from the "compare prices," to the featured or displayed on the panel itself is SEO work;

- Do you have topical authority to rank pages for the type of product? Reviews?
- Are you focused on Local or National SEO Ranking?
- Do you have the minimum via EEAT, (or more specifically for taking money over the internet), trust signals on the site such as phone number people can call! Address! About Us! Return Policy! et la.

If you click on the dots "..." next to your site listing in Google search, and then "source" > "more about this page."

Is there a gap between what your site has on the more about this page and what other sites, (which are featured), have? If there is sign up and fill in the "Google My Business" profile for your site or use off-page SEO to improve the trust rating for the site.

Non-"Google My Business," sites can fill in their "more about this page," information via off-site SEO, being listed on the BBB website, Yelp, et la. But this takes time, well worth it for the long game,

"Google My Business," is faster ... they send a letter to verify your address and use the phone to verify you received the letter; all in all about two weeks.

---

Basically upgrading to a featured listing is the result of Google being able to trust the information. They don't want untrustworthy information on the panel ... the bot needs to do its due diligence to verify the accuracy of the information.

---

Doing a review with a product offer may also be useful to know your standing in Google for the SEO related to the product.

### On an additional note for the category pages

The category pages, which are the breadcrumb pages, can have schema to list the product pages.

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": [
        "ItemList",
        "CollectionPage"
    ],
    "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "url": "https://example.com/product1/",
            "name": "page name"
        },{
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "url": "https://example.com/product2/",
            "name": "page name"
        },
...
```

This schema is being used by many for the category page, which is upstream from the breadcrumb ... but note it is not being used by major retailers such as eBay ... it may help in showing Google some expertise in the way of knowledge of a product category by volume of products available [not verified as beneficial at this time].

**Currently, Google does not list a carousel for products on their schema information pages, but if displayed it would look like ...**

You might consider a Carousel for category pages instead of the CollectionPage as well ... https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/carousel

---

[image]

---

### Updated

The pages need to be indexed for the products to be listed. And, Google may or can take some time before it graps the schema from the page for any type of featured listing or updates to any other part of Google search that uses schema.

Including but not limited to:

- Event Pages,
- Hours of operation
- Company logo
- About company information in the more about section

Google will list content from schema at times without all of the fields ... but it is best to have them, even if Google would of listed the content without it.

Comment: Hi Wayne, thank you very much for your details/info...new to this forum so I think the only way I can give you more info is to edit my question which I will do now

Comment: Hi Wayne, and you mentioned: "Going to the "compare prices" in the Google Panel will pull up all of the ecommerce shops with the correct schema"...lots of my competitors listed in the panels don't even have the shipping cost or stock info included in their product schema.

Comment: Hi Wayne, and what is interesting from the product schema example of ebay....no "sku", no "mpn", no "gtin", no "shippingDestination", no "deliveryTime"...and still showing in those panels

Comment: Hi Wayne, and of course all the info I provide in my product schema matches exactly what I show on my site and what I provide in my datafeed to the Google Merchant Center

Comment: @Richard I've updated my answer ... I would point out that the "review" property is not a requirement for a product offering and may change how Google treats the page, There review content on their search results page has been being updated a lot.

Comment: I have marked your answer as I really appreciate all your time with this. Yes, you are correct that the "review" property is not a requirement. However when I test the code on Google it does state in the product snippets "Missing Field" review(optional) and "Missing Field" aggregateRating(optional) so as I really try to eliminate the reasons why my shop isn't showing I included the "review" property to get a 100% green tick

Comment: so for now I will just wait and see, again it must be because my site got only indexed about 2 months ago

Comment: The review part is correct and if Google allows you to put in reviews you know you are in good shape with Google. But with the March 2024 Google update going on ... Normal business at Google may be slowed. So I'm thinking to keep it simple during the update periods.

Comment: Because the review rating is a featured snippet and one that some people have misused it adds more possible difficulties as a major Google update is in process. On a six-month-old site that was indexing all pages well ... it took me several weeks fo the reviews to pop up. ... I will say the reviews were put in place to determine the best structure for the webpage for reviews - none the less they were fair and accurate. ... I would suggest google is having problems with aggressive affiliate who are or were using AI to make massive sites with reviews.

Comment: Thanks for the "good shape" comment as Google does show all my review schema in the SERP results of my product final landing pages so it's a good sign. Yes agree with the March update. Guess we know more in April. Well on Reddit they mention alot that AI heavy sites got penalised the most.

Comment: And when you mentioned "it took me several weeks for the reviews to pop up", my experience so far is that when Google first indexed my pages about 2 months ago it showed all the structured data I had in place then straight away. But now it seems any change takes much longer and I guess because Google doesn't crawl my site as frequently. Thanks

Comment: And is busy as you mentioned with the current update

Answer (score 1):

For the critic reviews at the bottom of the knowledge graph, which can have an offer.

[image]

The ones I'm able to see today in Google are completely filled out; And, the author has a page with schema.

When you asked the question, there were critical reviews from retailers for the F-150 and Toyota Tundra. I'm not seeing those at this time, just high-authority magazines ... note the Google March Update is making adjustments to these types of reviews. They were the preferred method of affiliate sites that were creating content in mass, to create income.

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra",
    "image": [
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-1..v1645019742.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-2..v1645019742.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-3..v1645019742.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-4..v1645019742.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-5..v1645019742.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-6..v1645019742.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-7..v1645019742.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-8..v1645019742.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-9..v1645019743.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-10..v1645019743.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-11..v1645019743.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-12..v1645019743.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-13..v1645019743.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-14..v1645024118.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-15..v1645024118.jpg",
            "height": 1080,
            "width": 1920
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-16..v1645025741.png",
            "height": 1025,
            "width": 1919
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-17..v1645025741.png",
            "height": 1029,
            "width": 1917
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-18..v1645025741.png",
            "height": 1018,
            "width": 1917
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-19..v1645026472.jpg",
            "height": 720,
            "width": 1280
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-25..v1645027793.jpg",
            "height": 720,
            "width": 1280
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-26..v1645027793.png",
            "height": 1018,
            "width": 1917
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-27..v1645027793.png",
            "height": 1025,
            "width": 1919
        },
        {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/04FlAg3hzy16JocFyPQBRni-28..v1645027793.png",
            "height": 1029,
            "width": 1917
        }
    ],
    "url": "https://www.pcmag.com/reviews/samsung-galaxy-s22-ultra",
    "review": {
        "@type": "Review",
        "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
            "ratingValue": "4.0",
            "bestRating": 5,
            "worstRating": 0
        },
        "author": [
            {
                "@type": "Person",
                "name": "Sascha Segan",
                "url": "https://www.pcmag.com/authors/sascha-segan",
                "jobTitle": "Lead Analyst, Mobile",
                "image": {
                    "@type": "ImageObject",
                    "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/authors/02nzpbJYF0BwfMDzwDYOhcm..v1567806137.jpg",
                    "height": 300,
                    "width": 300
                }
            }
        ],
        "positiveNotes": {
            "@type": "ItemList",
            "itemListElement": [
                {
                    "@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": 1,
                    "name": "S Pen integration\r"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": 2,
                    "name": "Long battery life\r"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": 3,
                    "name": "Bright screen\r"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": 4,
                    "name": "Excellent reception in low-signal environments"
                }
            ]
        },
        "negativeNotes": {
            "@type": "ItemList",
            "itemListElement": [
                {
                    "@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": 1,
                    "name": "Very large\r"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": 2,
                    "name": "Expensive\r"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": 3,
                    "name": "Back scratches easily\r"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": 4,
                    "name": "Few camera improvements over predecessor"
                }
            ]
        },
        "datePublished": "2022-02-17T14:00:35+00:00"
    },
    "description": "A Galaxy Note by any other name",
    "offers": {
        "@type": "AggregateOffer",
        "highPrice": "1028.99",
        "lowPrice": "1199.99",
        "offerCount": 6,
        "offers": [
            {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra",
                "url": "https://www.amazon.com/SAMSUNG-Smartphone-Unlocked-Brightest-Processor/dp/B09MW17JQY",
                "availability": "OutOfStock",
                "price": "1028.99",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "seller": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "Amazon"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra",
                "url": "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/samsung-galaxy-s22-ultra-128gb-unlocked-phantom-black/6494439.p?skuId=6494439",
                "availability": "OutOfStock",
                "price": "242.99",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "seller": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "Best Buy"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra",
                "url": "https://www.att.com/buy/phones/samsung-galaxy-s22-ultra-256gb-burgundy.html",
                "availability": "OnlineOnly",
                "price": "1199.99",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "seller": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "AT&T Wireless"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra",
                "url": "https://www.verizon.com/smartphones/samsung-galaxy-s22-ultra/",
                "availability": "OnlineOnly",
                "price": "1199.99",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "seller": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "Verizon"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra",
                "url": "https://www.samsung.com/us/smartphones/galaxy-s22-ultra/buy/galaxy-s22-ultra-128gb-unlocked-sm-s908udraxaa/?modelCode=SM-S901ULVAVZW",
                "availability": "OnlineOnly",
                "price": "1199.99",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "seller": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "Samsung"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "name": "Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra",
                "url": "https://www.t-mobile.com/cell-phone/samsung-galaxy-s22-ultra",
                "availability": "OnlineOnly",
                "price": "1199.99",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "seller": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "T-Mobile"
                }
            }
        ],
        "priceCurrency": "USD"
    },
    "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "Samsung"
    }
}
```

And the author's schema.

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Sascha Segan",
    "url": "https://www.pcmag.com/authors/sascha-segan",
    "jobTitle": "Lead Analyst, Mobile",
    "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/authors/02nzpbJYF0BwfMDzwDYOhcm..v1567806137.jpg",
        "height": 300,
        "width": 300
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all those details...I won't be able to add that kind of info as pcmag for example has much more data...1 interesting question I have after your code(as I had that in my todo list) how important is the "datePublished" in the review schema? I know 1 competitor includes it(but has lots of incorrect values in the product schema, but is ranked high and in the Product Knowledge Panel)...as I read the "datePublished" is only "recommended"

Comment: Well keep watching for the product to appear in the database, once they start collecting the data from you they will under normal circumstances get new data normally in less than 24 hours ... today is not a normal day, I'm watching sites appear and disappear for some keywords. Two or three times over the course of an hour.

Comment: New content going in and out ... all content before the update is stable.

Comment: Thanks...lucky I managed to have my site indexed before the update...so again l can just wait and see if I one day make it into the Product Knowledge Panel as currently lots of pages show the old content in SERPs

Comment: Google's indexing new content it is just interesting to watch content published within the last 7 days shift around. With one site being indexed, then somebody else site, then two sites, then neither site ... It is all calm now with everybody indexed.

Comment: Yes, it seems like a rollercoaster...hope you are right that it is all calm now...going from other forums not even nearly